# SSH Server on Ubuntu no longer working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, networking, openssh

I restarted my server today and my SSH server stopped working. Docker is still running, the database is up, but connections to the SSH server are timing out.

I made sure that it’s not the firewall, tested it from another device from a different location, reinstalled the SSH server, but nothing seems to work (did it in rescue mode). I didn’t found anything important in the logs. Port seems to be closed from the outside, but logs indicate the server is running.

Docker is using the ports 80, 443, 53. I run a Cassandra database on the default ports. All of those are listening and I'm able to connect to them perfectly fine (except SSH as mentioned). SSH server is running on a custom port. I tried disabling UFW and changing the SSH port. I didn't change the SSH settings in a while and they worked after previous restarts.

Some output of: `cat /var/log/auth.log`

```
Oct  3 22:03:49 gd-1 sshd[1096]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 30XXX.
Oct  3 22:03:49 gd-1 sshd[1096]: Server listening on :: port 30XXX.
Oct  3 22:17:01 gd-1 CRON[19718]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  3 22:17:01 gd-1 CRON[19718]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct  3 22:35:11 gd-1 systemd-logind[644]: Power key pressed.
Oct  3 22:35:11 gd-1 systemd-logind[644]: Powering Off...
Oct  3 22:35:11 gd-1 systemd-logind[644]: System is powering down.
```

I'll add more info as requested, but I’m out of ideas. Any clues?

Comment: What does **not working** mean? Can you post the actual error message, if there is one, or explain what happens when you try to ssh into it?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Show `systemctl status ssh.service` output ... or anything else that is relevant. I mean how do you even know it's running? Also `lsof -i :22` ...

Comment: Connections are timing out. I looked through some logs in rescue mode and they contained information about the SSH server being started after restart and being stopped before restart.

Comment: As a side-note, given you mention rescue mode, there should be some clues in the logs of the live system even from rescue mode, right? Could you include the relevant lines from `/var/log/syslog` as well?!

Comment: No network settings issue? Like Docker stealing a network range for itself?

Comment: @TomKlein timeouts are but symptoms. You really need to give us more info on what the live system (i.e. when not in rescue mode) is doing. I presume you mount /dev, /proc etc in rescue mode and then all disks which would be available in live mode and then `chroot` into that?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Updating my answer with a little more info in a moment. For rescue mode, I mounted the /dev and chrooted into that. I can't access the server at the moment except by using the rescue mode.

Comment: Have you got an IP address on your host, or have your Docker instance(s) taken it? What about the bridge you'll have installed for Docker. Are you sure your host has an IP address? Do you have enough IP addresses or are you sharing the one and doing some sort of NAT with port forwarding? How is that configured?

Comment: I publish ports through Docker's publish-port-option. I can ping the server, Docker is using private IPs, and the database (separate from Docker) is listening on its default ports on the server's IP too. The server has currently two dedicated/static IPs assigned.